# How to fix "useActionData must be used within a data router." in remix

Tags: node.js, typescript, runtime-error, remix.run

```
`export default function Login() {
  const isSubmitting = useIsSubmitting("loginForm");
  const response: any = useActionData();

  if (response && response.status != 200) {
    toast.error(response.error, {
      id: response.error,
    });
  }

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        height: "100vh",
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Card variant="outlined" sx={{ width: "100%", maxWidth: 300, p: 2 }}>
        <ValidatedForm validator={loginValidator} method="post" id="loginForm">
          <Typography
            variant="h5"
            style={{ textAlign: "center", fontWeight: "bold" }}
          >
            LOGIN
          </Typography>
          <CustomTextField name="username" label="Username" />
          <CustomPasswordField name="password" label="Password" />
          <Button
            disabled={isSubmitting}
            style={{ margin: "10px 0" }}
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            type="submit"
              >
                {!isSubmitting ? "Login" : <CircularProgress />}
              </Button>
            </ValidatedForm>
          </Card>
        </div>
      );
    }`
```

This is my login.tsx and when I navigate to localhost:3000/auth/login this error comes

```
Error: useActionData must be used within a data router.  See https://reactrouter.com/routers/picking-a-router.
    at Object.invariant [as UNSAFE_invariant] (/home/dulanja/Adavii/11StreetSite/node_modules/@remix-run/router/history.ts:494:11)
    at useDataRouterState (/home/dulanja/Adavii/11StreetSite/node_modules/remix-validated-form/node_modules/@remix-run/react/node_modules/react-router/lib/hooks.tsx:838:3)
    at Object.useActionData (/home/dulanja/Adavii/11StreetSite/node_modules/remix-validated-form/node_modules/@remix-run/react/node_modules/react-router/lib/hooks.tsx:933:15)
    at useActionData (/home/dulanja/Adavii/11StreetSite/node_modules/remix-validated-form/node_modules/@remix-run/react/dist/components.js:702:25)
    at useErrorResponseForForm (/home/dulanja/Adavii/11StreetSite/node_modules/remix-validated-form/src/internal/hooks.ts:31:22)
    at ValidatedForm (/home/dulanja/Adavii/11StreetSite/node_modules/remix-validated-form/src/ValidatedForm.tsx:265:24)
    at renderWithHooks (/home/dulanja/Adavii/11StreetSite/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:5724:16)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (/home/dulanja/Adavii/11StreetSite/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:5797:15)
    at renderElement (/home/dulanja/Adavii/11StreetSite/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:6012:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/home/dulanja/Adavii/11StreetSite/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.development.js:6170:11)
```

I used this command, npm install react-router-dom@latest @types/react-router-dom@latest and this is worked well in a different branch. After I merged to the main branch, the above error came... I used the above command again but my error did not resolve.

Comment: Are you using `Remix.run` or are you just using `react-router-dom`?

Comment: I'm using Remix.run

Comment: I see, thanks, I just wanted to confirm if your post was correctly tagged. If you are using Remix.run then you shouldn't be including `react-router-dom` as a project dependency or trying to import from it, `@remix-run`/`@remix-run/react` should re-export anything you need from `react-router-dom`. `@types/react-router-dom@latest` is also only the RRDv5 type bindings, so they are completely unnecessary in RRDv6 (*RRDv6 is completely written in Typescript*). See if uninstalling these two packages helps.

Answer (score 0):

> In v6.4, new routers were introduced that support the new [data APIs](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.22.2/routers/picking-a-router#data-apis):

- createBrowserRouter
- createMemoryRouter
- createHashRouter
- createStaticRouter

You must use `useActionData()` hook within a data router.

e.g. `createBrowserRouter()` will create a data router.

`App.tsx`:

```
import { Outlet, useActionData } from 'react-router-dom';

export const App = () => {
  const actionData = useActionData();
  return (
    <div>
      {actionData}
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
};
```

`index.tsx`:

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  Route,
  RouterProvider,
} from 'react-router-dom';

import { App } from './App';

let router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
      <Route path="child" element={<App />} />
    </Route>
  ),
  {
    hydrationData: {
      actionData: {
        '0-0': 'child action',
      },
    },
  }
);

createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-eaudsv?file=src%2Findex.tsx)